# Windows does not resume from Hibernation on first attempt

Tags: windows-7, power-management, hibernate

When I press hibernation icon my laptop, it copies the open programs on hard and turns off the system but after I press power switch botton windows doesn't load and a blank screen appears. I turn  off the system by pressing power switch and turn it on again.

After turning it on the windows loads normally and resuming Windows will appear. My question is why windows doesn't load programs copied on the hdd firstly and loads after turning it off and on? Thanks all

Comment: something like that happens with my computer, but in anoter way: SOMETIMES I turn on my notebook after hibernation and the leds and cooler indicate that it is working, but nothing appears on screen - after some seconds, all leds and cooler are turned off and then turned on again and then all is in order. I cannot understand that behavior...

Answer (score 0):

It could be how it is configured in control panel/power options/advanced the action of the power on button, i would also check that in your BIOS menu(many let you configure there these butttons). Anyway, in laptops and some PCs keyboards, there is a hibernation or suspension key. I would check if there's one for that.

Also, try hitting cursor keys after/before hitting the power or hibernation button. It might be having both suspension and hibernation at a time, or it might be even some graphical problem, ie, screensaver (deactivate it to eliminate as a factor).

If you totally switch off, is expected that you would not recover your software sessions.